# How to add timeout on mouseleave action with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, hover, mouseevent

i have menu on list, this is html:

```
 <div class="main_menu">
   <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" target="_self"><span>Content</span></a>
        <div id="submenu_01" class="sub_menu_main"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" target="_self"><span>Content</span></a>
        <div id="submenu_02" class="sub_menu_main"></div>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Now - on hover for list element i need to show `sub_menu_main` div which is deppend for each li and have diferent content. Additionally i want to have some timeout on mouseleve action so that changing the div element of the list for a while remained outdoor, and another has not yet appeared.

This is my function:

```
$('.main_menu ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.sub_menu_main').css('display','block');
});
$('.main_menu ul').find('li').each().mouseleave(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sub_menu_main').css('display','none');
    },2000);
});
```

thx for help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: :) first - i can't obtain timeout effect and second when i hover each li element the `.sub_menu_main` div's is opening of all of the blocks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `.each()` because `.mouseleave()` will bind itself automatically to each `li` like this

```
$('.main_menu ul').find('li').mouseleave(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('.sub_menu_main').hide();
   },2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said exactly what the problem is, but for starters you don't need the empty `each()` call:

```
$('.main_menu ul').find('li').mouseleave(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.sub_menu_main').css('display','none');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Other than that, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it isn't pretty, but maybe somebody can help clean it up:

```
function getSubMenu(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var submenu = $target;
    if ($target.is('a') || $target.is('span') || $target.is('li')) {
        var $li = $target.parents('li');
        $submenu = $li.find('.sub_menu_main');
    }
    return $submenu;
}
$('.sub_menu_main').hide();
$('.main_menu ul li').hover(function(e) {
    var $submenu = getSubMenu(e);
    $($submenu).show();
}, function(e) {
    var $submenu = getSubMenu(e);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $($submenu).hide();
    }, 2000);
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K5yt2/)**